# How to generate a pandas dataframe from ordereddict?

Tags: pandas

How can i generated a pandas dataframe from an ordereddict?

I have tried using the dataframe.from_dict method but that is not giving me the expected dataframe.

What is the best approach to convert an ordereddict into a list of dicts?

Comment: Please show the code you have tried. Otherwise it is hard to say why it didn't work.

Answer (score 13):

A [bug](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/3282) in Pandas did not respect the key ordering of OrderedDict objects converted to a DataFrame via the from_dict call. Fixed in Pandas 0.11.